# Refresh input button not refreshing

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hi I have two input buttons, one continues to the next page (test32_page2.php) and a refresh input which refreshes the page (test32.php)

Input continue:

`<input type='submit' name="submitcart" value='Continue' onclick="f1.action='test32_page2.php'; return true;" style="visibility: <?=$submitshow?>;">`

and the other input is a refresh:

`<input type='submit' name="submit" value='Refresh' onclick="f1.action="test32.php"; return true;" style="visibility: <?=$refreshshow?>;">`

Once the user inputs their values and presses continue they are then processed on the following page, however if they then go back to test32.php and press refresh they are then sent to the following page again (test32_page2.php) instead of reloading test32.php again. How can I make sure that when refresh input is pressed it only reloads the page not do anything else? Is this a cache/meta issue?

I've been around and around in circles on this one, partly I think because the different browsers seem to do different things.

Help much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: write test32.php in single quote because onclick have double quote in refresh button..

Comment: Seriously it was that easy.....oh man it works!! Thanks for your help.